# semi-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x^2 & \text{if}\; x \not= 0 \\
-1 &\text{if}\; x = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Please help me prove it follows this definition.
$f$ is lower semi-continuous iff $f^{-1} ((-\infty,M]):=\{ x  \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq M \}$ is closed.
I want to show $f^{-1} ((-\infty,0])$ is closed, then f is lower semi continuous.

Comment: And what do you get for $f^{-1} ((-\infty,0])$?

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1} ((-\infty,0])=\{x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \le 0\}=\{0\}.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: why? I don't  understand

Comment: @PpooKkyPaeko What don't you understand ? Why is $f^{-1}((-\infty,0]) = \{0\}$, or how to proceed from here?

Comment: How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The function $f(x)$ maps $[-x_0,x_0]$ to $\{-1\}\cup (0,x_0^2]\subseteq(-\infty,M]$ with $M=x_0^2$. What if either $x_0$ is $0$ or $M<-1$?